# Printing Jagged Array

Tags: c#, arrays, printing

I am writing a program that will take a jagged array and print said jagged array. I used a foreach loop to attempt to print the array. Whenever I would go to run the program and see if the Jagged array will print it fails. I also tried just a for loop to print the array. Every time I would go to run the program I get System.IndexOutOfRange has been thrown. "Index was outside the bounds of the Array for my for loop. I tried commenting the loop out and it would do the same thing for when I tried to call the min and max method.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int NUMBER_OF_CITIES = 9;
            int i;
            int[][] miles = new int[NUMBER_OF_CITIES][];
            miles[0] = new int[1] { 0 };
            miles[1] = new int[1] { 290 };
            miles[2] = new int[2] { 373, 102 };
            miles[3] = new int[3] { 496, 185, 228 };
            miles[4] = new int[4] { 193, 110, 208, 257 };
            miles[5] = new int[5] { 214, 90, 165, 270, 73 };
            miles[6] = new int[6] { 412, 118, 150, 81, 191, 198 };
            miles[7] = new int[7] { 222, 86, 173, 285, 41, 34, 201 };
            miles[8] = new int[8] { 112, 207, 301, 360, 94, 155, 288, 141 };
            miles[9] = new int[9] { 186, 129, 231, 264, 25, 97, 194, 66, 82 };
            int index = 0;
            foreach (int[] milesRows in miles)
            {
                Console.Write("\t" + ++index);
                for (int j = 0;j < milesRows.Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(milesRows[j] + "\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }


            Min(miles[7]);
            Max(miles[7]);
            Console.WriteLine("The clossest is: " + Min(miles[7]));
            Console.WriteLine("The farthest is: " + Max(miles[7]));
        }
```

Comment: `miles[9] = new int[9]...` this line causes the issue... you have created `miles` with length 9. that means the index of the array can be from 0 to 8. Try removing `miles[9] = new int[9]...` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined the max number of elements in the array as 9 (NUMBER_OF_CITIES) but you have 10 elements in your array (from miles[0] to miles[9]) which is why it went out of bounds. Change:

> const int NUMBER_OF_CITIES = 9;

to

> const int NUMBER_OF_CITIES = 10;

Comment: Awesome thank you! I am new to C#. I forgot that arrays start at 0. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

The immediate cause of the problem is incorrect length of the array:

```
 const int NUMBER_OF_CITIES = 9;

 int[][] miles = new int[NUMBER_OF_CITIES][];
```

which means that `miles` have items in `0..8` range; but you put a line *out of range*

```
 // 9 is out of range
 miles[9] = new int[9] { 186, 129, 231, 264, 25, 97, 194, 66, 82 };
```

In order to git rid of such errors, try to declare and initialize `miles` in *one go* and let .net compute all the `Length` for you:

```
 // note, that we don't specify Length anywhere and let .net do it itself
 int[][] miles = new int[][] {
   new int[] { 0 },
   new int[] { 290 },
   new int[] { 373, 102 },
   new int[] { 496, 185, 228 },
   new int[] { 193, 110, 208, 257 },
   new int[] { 214, 90, 165, 270, 73 },
   new int[] { 412, 118, 150, 81, 191, 198 },
   new int[] { 222, 86, 173, 285, 41, 34, 201 },
   new int[] { 112, 207, 301, 360, 94, 155, 288, 141 },
   new int[] { 186, 129, 231, 264, 25, 97, 194, 66, 82 },
 };
```